# How to see HTML hierarchy of a page

Tags: html, dom, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for a tool that will label the components on a page with their position in  the DOM, so I can see immediately, then, that a particular div is a child of some other div and had some children divs. I know I've seen this tool but it was a long time ago and I don't recall where it came from.  Chrome Dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to Chrome's inspector. Just right click any DOM element on the page and click "Inspect element"

from there you can see the hierarchy of HTML

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/ for more info

Comment: No, it's more than that.  This puts a label on the page and told me the parent of a <div>

Answer (score 0):

After selecting an element, this breadcrumb shows you all of the parents of the currently-selected element.

[image: breadcrumb]

Comment: But the breadcrumb is not wide enough to show all the parents and it has no scrollbar...so how to solve this problem?